# Re-writing $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x+2y} \mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$ with the $x$ and $y$ directions first

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

Can you guys tell me, with reasoning, how to write this triple integral in $x$ and $y$ direction first? I found it very hard to do through graphing.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x+2y}  \mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: i don't know of any easier way -- plot the region and re-parameterize it

Answer (score 0):

Your initial condition has the following conditions:
$$ 0\le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le x, 0 \le z \le x+2y. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Notice the order of this: You end with $x$ so inequality inequality involving $x$ should not depend on $y,z$. This gives you $0 \le x \le 1$. You go with $y$ second to last which means inequality involving $y$ can depend on $z$. This gives you $0 \le y \le x$. Similarly, you get $0\le z \le x+2y$.

Now, if you want to write the integral in $x,y$ direction first, which means you end with $z$, and therefore inequality involving $z$ should not depend on $x,y$. Look at $\eqref{1}$ and you can only get $0\le z \le x+2y\le 3x \le 3$ or $0 \le z \le 3$. If you want to go with $y$ next then similarly, inequality involving $y$ can depend on $z$. Look at $\eqref{1}$ to obtain the most strict bound, you get $\max \{ 0,\frac{z-x}{2}\} \le y \le x \le 1$. Since we don't want to involve $x$ in this so you from $\frac{z-x}{2} \ge \frac{z-1}{2}$ since $x \le 1$, you would get $\max\{ 0,\frac{z-1}{2}\} \le y \le 1$.

Lastly, we go for $x$, look at $\eqref{1}$ and we find $0 \le y \le x \le 1$ and $x \ge z-2y$ so your answer is $\max \{y,z-2y\} \le x \le 1$. Thus, you obtain your domain as
$$0 \le z \le 3, \max\{ 0,\frac{z-1}{2}\} \le y \le 1, \max \{y,z-2y\} \le x \le 1. \tag{2} \label{2}$$
If you are unsure, you can check by showing that $\eqref{1}\iff \eqref{2}$. What we did above gives $\eqref{1}\implies \eqref{2}$. To prove the converse, pick $(x,y,z)$ from $\eqref{2}$ and show that such point satisfies $\eqref{1}$.

---

@Andy Lam: It seems I also got the wrong answer when I just type
$$\int_0^3\int_{\max\{0,\frac{z-1}{2}\}}^1\int_{\max\{y,z-2y \}}^1 dxdydz$$
into Sagemath (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3115903/calculating-iterated-integral-using-sagemath)). However, if I break down $\eqref{2}$ to avoid using $\max$, which is:
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^{z/3}\int_{z-2y}^1dxdydz+
\int_0^1\int_{z/3}^1\int_y^1dxdydz+
\int_1^3\int_{z/3}^1\int_y^1dxdydz+
\int_1^3\int_{(z-1)/2}^{z/3}\int_{z-2y}^{1}dxdydz$$
then the answer turns out to be correct, which is $2/3$.

---

**Edit number 2:** It seems the problem about Sagemath as I mentioned above has been solved and actually, my answer is correct, i.e.

$$\int_0^3\int_{\max\{0,\frac{z-1}{2}\}}^1\int_{\max\{y,z-2y \}}^1 dxdydz=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x+2y}  \mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=2/3.$$

Comment: can you explain what max is ?

Comment: Max is maximum. So you $\max\{y,z-2y\}$ means the maximum of $y$ and $z-2y$. To avoid the $\max$ when calculating integral, I think the best choice is to divide the domain into smaller one. For example, you can consider separate case where $0 \le z\le 1$ to get $\max\{0,(z-1)/2\}=0$ and $1 \le z \le 3$ to get $\max \{0,(z-1)/2\}=(z-1)/2$.

Comment: I just calculate the integral you just show me, and the result is different from the original one

Comment: @AndyLam: Thanks for pointing that out. I've just edited my answer.

Comment: @AndyLam: Actually, it's the correct domain. I just happened to use Sagemath incorrectly.